# Segmentation Fault using bcp to connect to Azure SQL database on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: azure-sql-database, ubuntu-16.04, bcp

I am trying to copy data from an Ubuntu server 16.04 to an Azure SQL database.  It seems the best way to do this is with the `bcp` utility but I am open to any options.

I have followed the instructions on this page for installing the bcp utility on Ubuntu 16.04 and it all seemed to go OK. (Note, I did not install the whole sql server; only the mssql-tools as described on the link.  Not sure if that is the problem)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu

When I try to copy data with the following command I get a segmentation fault.  In fact, I also get that when trying to generate a format file or do anything really.

```
$> bcp bcptest in /home/data/bcptest.dat -d MyDB  -U myusername -S myserver.database.windows.net -P mypassword -c
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Changing/removing the `-c` flag does not help.  I should note that if I put the password wrong it fails on authentication so I know it is at least getting that far.

The only thing that actually works for me is checking the version:

```
$> bcp -v
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 14.0.0001.246
```

For what it's worth, I can get the `freebcp` utility working with the same database but that is giving me errors like this when copying more than a few dozen rows.  That's for a separate post, I suppose.

```
Msg 20004, Level 9
Read from the server failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting segmentation faults when using bcp on Ubuntu 16.04 (and Ubuntu 16.10 and Centos 7 when testing those OS versions as well).

I had also installed the mssql-tools for Ubuntu 16.04 according to this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu

A new version of msodbcsql (13.1.3.0-1) for Ubuntu 16.04 has been released which fixes this segmentation fault problem for me.

```
# To fix the bcp segmentation fault problem on my ubuntu 16.04 server I did this:

$ sudo apt-get update
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
...
msodbcsql/xenial 13.1.3.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 13.1.1.0-1]
...
$ sudo apt-get install msodbcsql
```

After updating to msodbcsql (13.1.3.0-1) the segmentation faults are gone

Testing:

```
$ bcp mytable out myfile.csv -c -t ';' -U myuser -P mypass -S myserver.database.secure.windows.net -d mydatabase

# OK - no segmentation fault - data is bulk copied to outfile
```